# Sending Hex code using pyusb

Tags: libusb, pyusb

I have been trying for 4 days now to send the hex code `10 80 00 00 00 00 00 00` to a USB device connected to my raspberry pi running debian.

I've tried libusb with c but I have no idea what I am doing. I thought PyUSB would be a better solution but ive found zero documentation for what I need and the tutorial did'nt help.

I can find the device using

```
import usb.core
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x12BF, idProduct=0xFF03)
```

But I cant find any information on how to send the above hex code. My device is a usb based relay. It works fine on windows in a vb HID application but I am struggling here. seem to be going round in circles.

Comment: Im assuming i need to use some sort of command like dev.ctrl_transfer(0x40,0x09,0,0,[0x10,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us, how is the USB communication with the device? Is it a bulk transfer?
(see this link for more details:
http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml )

For instance, if you are using a bulk communication via an Endpoint you could try something like this (as seen here http://pyusb.sourceforge.net/docs/1.0/tutorial.html):

```
endpoint.write(endpointnumber, data, interfacenumber)
```

If you want to send a hex value, let's say 0xFF via the endpoint 2, interface 0, try something like:

```
endpoint.write(2, '\xFF', 0)
```

I hope this helps...